# Spring Model view output

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, el

I have this jsp code which fails to output the model correctly:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Welcome File</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    ${message1} 
</body> 
</html>
```

The controller to redirect to this page is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/triangle") 
   public ModelAndView triangle() { 
       String message = "<br><div align='center'><h1>Triangle.<h1><br>"; 
       ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springContext.xml"); 
       Triangle obj = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle"); 

       message += obj.draw(); 
       System.out.println("Inside shape controller : " + message);
       ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("message1", message);
        modelAndView.setViewName("output");
       return modelAndView; 
   }
```

The page displays ${message1} verbatime,instead of the content within the string.
What am i doign wrong?

Comment: Can you try adding `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` at the top of the file? Also what version of servlet-api are you using?

Comment: Missing `<%@page %>` maybe?

Comment: Did you add `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>` to your `jsp` file?

Comment: Make sure you have a correct EL version and that your web.xml has the proper web-app version, else EL will not work. Regarding your control **never** construct an ApplicationContext, you should inject the dependencies (unless you want to run out of resource, get outof memory errors etc.).

Comment: as a test, add ${2+2} to your page. If it displays 4 then the version of JSP you are using supports EL expressions. if it displays ${2+2} then you need to include a JSP tag library (perhaps JSTL) and display the value with a tag (maybe c:out value="${blah}").

Comment: I see that you are including JSTL core.  try using <c:out ...> to display your model value.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @IUnknown can you try this, something like this:

```
return new ModelAndView("/path/to/view").addObject("message1", message);
```

Or,

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/path/to/view");
modelAndView.addObject("message1", message);
return modelAndView;
```

**I hope these helped :)**